# LINQ Lambda to form a Nested Object/Collection from a Flat List, it's not hierarchical but to group similar data

Tags: c#, linq

Note: I don't have a tree with parent & child relation instead trying to group similar code & store together and form nested objects/collection

I have a scenario where I have data flattened & wanted to form nested collection based on code & store.

```
public class Item 
{
   public int Code { get; set; }
   public string Price { get; set; }
   public int Store { get; set; }
   public string PriceType { get; set; }
}    

public class PriceDto
{
  public string PriceType { get; set; }
  public string Price { get; set; }
}

public class ItemVm
{
   public int Code { get; set; }
   public int Store { get; set; }
   public List<PriceDto> SalePrice { get; set; }
   public List<PriceDto> PermPrice { get; set; }
}   

public static class IEnumerableExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
        {
            HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
            foreach (TSource element in source)
            {
                if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                {
                    yield return element;
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

I have below code to form nested collection from flattened list.

```
         IList<Item> items = new List<Item>() { 
                        new Item() { Code = 1, Price = "3.83",  Store = 1202, PriceType = "Sale"} ,
                        new Item() { Code = 1, Price = "4.10",  Store = 1202, PriceType = "Perm"} ,
                        new Item() { Code = 2, Price = "3.00",  Store = 1315, PriceType = "Perm"} ,
                        new Item() { Code = 3, Price = "1.99" , Store = 1420, PriceType = "Sale"} ,
                        new Item() { Code = 3, Price = "2.25" , Store = 1420, PriceType = "Perm" } 
                    };
        
        //Distinct Code, Store & then form nested collection by loop
        
        var itemsList = items.Select(
         i => new ItemVm { Code = i.Code, Store = i.Store,  }
         ).DistinctBy(d => new { d.Code,d.Store }).ToList();
        
        foreach( var i in itemsList) 
        {
            i.PermPrice = items.Where(x=> x.Code == i.Code && x.Store == i.Store && x.PriceType == "Perm").Select(d => new PriceDto
                                                                    { Price = d.Price, PriceType = d.PriceType }).ToList();
            i.SalePrice = items.Where(x=> x.Code == i.Code && x.Store == i.Store && x.PriceType == "Sale").Select(d => new PriceDto
                                                                    { Price = d.Price, PriceType = d.PriceType }).ToList();
        }
```

Is there a better way than this to form the nested collection in single LINQ query ?

Any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like `GroupBy`

Comment: @Ivan Steoev how would it work with GroupBy, as group by will get only First row or only the key values in the group by not the other values like the PermPrice & SalePrice i got using foreach loop

Comment: Hmm,  coming from SQL world? LINQ `GroupBy` is different - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/group-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `GroupBy`

```cs
var itemsList = items
    .GroupBy(d => new { d.Code, d.Store })
    .Select(g => new ItemVm 
    { 
        Code = g.Key.Code, 
        Store = g.Key.Store,
        PermPrice = g.Where(x => x.PriceType == "Perm")
            .Select(d => new PriceDto { Price = d.Price, PriceType = d.PriceType })
            .ToList(),
        SalePrice = g.Where(x => x.PriceType == "Sale")
            .Select(d => new PriceDto { Price = d.Price, PriceType = d.PriceType })
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```